# Uploading file with the uri starting with content://

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I am reading a file from android and uploading it to a remote server.I am getting the file in the form of

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3
```

Since i am using react-native, can the uri above used as a file path?.

I can get the exact file path but when the file picker gets the file and the file has spaces, the picker cannot read the file but the uri takes into account spaces.

What can be done to use `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3` as the file path?.

Comment: you need to create plugin which would use `ContentResolver.openInputStream()` to get the uri content

Comment: I think i have found one https://github.com/Wraptime/react-native-get-real-path   I am currently testing it.

Comment: terrible idea ... not all uris has "real path" ... if you wana have real path for sure then do copy of  stream taken from `ContentResolver.openInputStream()`

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by ` not all uris has "real path"`

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html

Comment: Great, i will have a look immediately. Thanks.

Comment: That plugin will work for very few `Uri` values, and it will not work for your `Uri`. A better plugin would copy the content to a temporary file, upload from the temporary file, then delete the temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want , its something like this

```
var x = "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3"
const file = {
  uri:  x,
  name: "nameFile",
}

const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('Files', file);

fetch('URL', {
   ...
```

Comment: I'm also trying to the same thing. However, fetch with such a uri fails with Network Error